# error 404 when load image over WWW class in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, coroutine

I tried to download image from my server over www. In UnityPlayer it is all right, but when i run app on xcode it is crash.

I check log on server and there was no request from ios only from webplayer:

> 109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:53:18 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 604 "-" "cocktailparty/27
>   CFNetwork/893.14.2 Darwin/17.3.0" 452 746 0 125187
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:53:39 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 14 "-" "cocktailparty/27
>   CFNetwork/893.14.2 Darwin/17.3.0" 563 156 0 2266
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:53:39 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 170 "-" "cocktailparty/27
>   CFNetwork/893.14.2 Darwin/17.3.0" 421 312 0 1807
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:53:43 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 992 "-" "cocktailparty/27
>   CFNetwork/893.14.2 Darwin/17.3.0" 430 1134 0 243826
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:53:45 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 604 "-" "cocktailparty/27
>   CFNetwork/893.14.2 Darwin/17.3.0" 452 746 0 2482
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:54:05 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 604 "-" "cocktailparty/27
>   CFNetwork/893.14.2 Darwin/17.3.0" 452 746 0 2452
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:54:25 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 13 "-" "UnityPlayer/2017.3.0f3
>   (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)" 595 155 0 1760
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:54:25 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 170 "-" "UnityPlayer/2017.3.0f3
>   (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)" 414 312 0 1034
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:54:29 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 992 "-" "UnityPlayer/2017.3.0f3
>   (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)" 423 1134 0 263959
>   109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:54:32 +0300] "POST /unityConnect.php HTTP/1.0" 200 604 "-" "UnityPlayer/2017.3.0f3
>   (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)" 445 746 0 3588
>   **109.252.44.138 - - [17/Feb/2018:09:54:32 +0300] "GET /img/0002.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 73962 "-" "UnityPlayer/2017.3.0f3 (UnityWebRequest/1.0,
>   libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)"**

Code:

```c#
public void GetFullReceiptMySQL(Dictionary <string, string> [] newReader)
{
    StartCoroutine(StartLoad(newReader[0]["id"], newReader));
}

IEnumerator StartLoad(string idCocktail, Dictionary <string, string> [] newReader)
{
    // testing parameter 0002, image 0002 present on server  
    string imageUrl = GetFullSourceCocktailImage("0002");
    WWW www = new WWW(imageUrl);
    Debug.Log(imageUrl);
    // Wait for download to complete
    Debug.Log ("Done1? " + www.isDone +  " progress " + www.progress + " or with error " + www.error) ;
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log ("Done2? " + www.isDone +  " progress " + www.progress + " or with error " + www.error) ;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("error " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("image ready" + www.error);
        RawImage image = GetComponent<KeeperScript>().imageCocktailInReceipt;
        Texture2D newTexture = new Texture2D(www.texture.width, www.texture.height);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(newTexture as Texture2D);
        image.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture= newTexture;
        MakeAllReceipt(newReader);
    }
    DestroyImmediate(www.texture);
    www.Dispose();
    www = null;
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();

}
```

In XCode in logs there was error 404

Comment: if you print out the imageUrl string, does it work in browser?

Comment: yes. For example: http://vh190639.eurodir.ru/img/0002.jpg